# How to create sub menu in Navigation drawer

Tags: android

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment  {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
     * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ExpandableListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    List<String> groupList;
    List<String> childList;
    Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollection;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
        // awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
        // actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         createGroupList();

            createCollection();

            mDrawerListView = (ExpandableListView) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
            final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                    getActivity(), groupList, laptopCollection);
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

            //setGroupIndicatorToRight();

            mDrawerListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                            groupPosition, childPosition);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    return true;
                }
            });
            return mFragmentContainerView;


        }

        private void createGroupList() {
            groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
            groupList.add("HP");
            groupList.add("Dell");
            groupList.add("Lenovo");
            groupList.add("Sony");
            groupList.add("HCL");
            groupList.add("Samsung");
        }

        private void createCollection() {
            // preparing laptops collection(child)
            String[] hpModels = { "HP Pavilion G6-2014TX", "ProBook HP 4540",
                    "HP Envy 4-1025TX" };
            String[] hclModels = { "HCL S2101", "HCL L2102", "HCL V2002" };
            String[] lenovoModels = { "IdeaPad Z Series", "Essential G Series",
                    "ThinkPad X Series", "Ideapad Z Series" };
            String[] sonyModels = { "VAIO E Series", "VAIO Z Series",
                    "VAIO S Series", "VAIO YB Series" };
            String[] dellModels = { "Inspiron", "Vostro", "XPS" };
            String[] samsungModels = { "NP Series", "Series 5", "SF Series" };

            laptopCollection = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

            for (String laptop : groupList) {
                if (laptop.equals("HP")) {
                    loadChild(hpModels);
                } else if (laptop.equals("Dell"))
                    loadChild(dellModels);
                else if (laptop.equals("Sony"))
                    loadChild(sonyModels);
                else if (laptop.equals("HCL"))
                    loadChild(hclModels);
                else if (laptop.equals("Samsung"))
                    loadChild(samsungModels);
                else
                    loadChild(lenovoModels);

                laptopCollection.put(laptop, childList);
            }
        }

        private void loadChild(String[] laptopModels) {
            childList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String model : laptopModels)
                childList.add(model);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private void setGroupIndicatorToRight() {
            /* Get the screen width */
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int width = dm.widthPixels;

            mDrawerListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - getDipsFromPixel(35), width
                    - getDipsFromPixel(5));
        }

        // Convert pixel to dip
        public int getDipsFromPixel(float pixels) {
            // Get the screen's density scale
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
            return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
        }









        /*mDrawerListView = (ExpandableListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        selectItem(position);
                    }
                });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
                .getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3), }));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);*/



    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null
                && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
     * drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId
     *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout
     *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                         * "open drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                         * "close drawer" description for
                                         * accessibility
                                         */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                    // prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                            .apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
        // them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
        // See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
        // action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
     * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
     * screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
     * implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

I'm getting errors and its not working with expandable list view.
I've been working on this for five days and not getting any help on internet.
Please help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use expandable ListView inside navigation drawer.

Refer this [Expandable List in Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest)

use `setGroupData()` and `setChildGroupData()` function from main activity ti initialize list.